# What is the sequence of diagnostics I should run on a troubled diskdrive on centos (on AWS)

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services

Running CentOS release 5.4 (Final) on AWS

All of a sudden a disk drive went awol on me.

the device is /dev/sdh ... what do I do to start recovering it?

dmesg results in:

```
 sdh: unknown partition table
```

e2fsck /dev/sdh results in

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]# e2fsck /dev/sdh

e2fsck 1.39 (29-May-2006)
Couldn't find ext2 superblock, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdh

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdh results in

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]#  e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdh
e2fsck 1.39 (29-May-2006)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdh

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make a backup of the disk (if you have space) with

```
dd if=/dev/sdh of=your-file.bin
```

Then you can use some restore utility like `testdisk` or whatever you want, test smart capabilities, etc.

You can follow the e2fsck instructions and try with `e2fsck -b 8193`, for example.

Comment: thanks doing that now (whew) ... could I offer u consulting to help me fix this.

Comment: really sorry, but i have a really bad day today. I have a lot of work. But testdisk is very good finding lost partitions, and in its home page there are a lot of help, with examples an so. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step